# How can create a Cross Symbol Using CSS?

Tags: html, css

Is there any Option to create a cross christian symbol USING `HTML` and `CSS`?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/stackmanoz/r6E9p/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
&dagger;
```

`&#8224;`

USE This html Entities for making Cross

Comment: The character “†” is U+2020 DAGGER, also known as obelisk or obelus, of unknown or debated origin, used for various special purposes. While it may be seen as Latin cross and used e.g. to denote death, it is incorrect to regard it as “the Christian cross”.

Answer (score 6):

Following is the list of various Cross Symbols and their HTML code

```
☦ Eastern Christian Cross &#9766; 
☧ Chi Rho Cross &#9767;
☨ Patriarchal Cross &#9768;
☩ Greek Cross &#9769;
✚ Greek Cross heavy &#10010;
✙ Greek Cross outline &#10009;    
☓ Saltire, St.Andrew’s Cross &#9747;
✝ Latin Roman Cross &#10013;
✞ Latin Cross 3D shadow &#10014;
✟ Latin Cross outline &#10015;
```

You can use them in HTML or CSS.

see the following link for more details
http://www.sabinanore.com/design/web-design/html-special-symbols/

Comment: All of these come with different font problems, so you should make sure that you have a `font-family` value that contains a good list of fonts that actually contain the character you are using (and have an acceptable glyph for it). For example, LATIN CROSS “✝” is not present in most computers that do not have Microsoft Office installed (Office comes with Arial Unicode MS font, which contains this character).

Answer (score 1):

You can get cross using,

```
Entity Name  &dagger; †  
Decimal Number &#134; † 
HexNumber &#x86; †
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this:

```
&#10013; -> ✝
```

and

```
&#10014; -> ✞
```

For more HTML codes for symbols: http://www.danshort.com/HTMLentities/?w=dingb

Answer (score 0):

I think you may find many symbols from here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cultural,_political,_and_religious_symbols_in_Unicode

Answer (score 0):

Here is HTML special character link.
http://ikreator.com/special-characters/#crosses

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/billymoon/tRG72/

HTML

```
<div id="horizontal"></div>
<div id="vertical"></div>
```

CSS

```
#horizontal{
    width: 100px;
    height: 10px;
    background-color: goldenrod;
    top: 60px;
    left: 10px;
    position: absolute;
}
#vertical{
    width: 10px;
    height: 180px;
    background-color: goldenrod;
    top: 10px;
    left: 55px;
    position: absolute;
}
```